# How do I create a container with multiple network interfaces for different functions?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can't find the best answers to this, hence I'm posting my question here.

How can I create a container with multiple network interfaces?

- 1st network expose the port so that others can access;
- 2nd network the container needs to access a gateway device;

```
                       -------------------     -----------------------
 -----------      .---| port:3000 exposed |---| host / lan can access |
| container |----<     -------------------     -----------------------
 -----------      '_   -------------------     -----------------------
                    '-| 192.168.1.0/24    |---| access to 192.168.1.1 |
                       -------------------     -----------------------
```

I have atleast 3 network interface on my host, wlan0, eth0, eth1(usb-lan adapter).

I have the gateway connected on eth1.
eth0 is where i need to expose the container port.
wlan0 used for management of the host thru ssh.

Is this possible within the container?
I'm open to docker or docker-compose solution.

Comment: In general, you don't have this level of control over Docker's networking setup.  A container has one network interface and you can publish specific ports to specific host interfaces, but that's about the end of it.  It seems like the right combination of `ports:` might be able to do what you describe but that would totally be (non-programming) configuration outside the container.

Comment: Can i atleast make this work on 1 interface though? I might be able to use one interface, then run a proxy server from the host to forward request to container...

Comment: Do you have an existing Compose setup (with `ports:`) or `docker run` commands (with `-p` options)?  By default those options will publish the specified container ports to all host interfaces, but you can limit that, and that doesn't affect what (artificial) network interfaces the container itself has; can you use that to accomplish your goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to mark this as an answer since there is no possible way to do it in current version of docker / docker-compose.

Anyway, the way I solved this is instead of working with network interfaces, i created a simple systemd service, for ex. i need to send command to the gateway, so i made a simple script that runs in the background and READS a common file that is shared between the HOST and CONTAINER. This is possible since we can mount volume and share that file. CONTAINER will write to file "SEND", then HOST can read it and executes command, when it finishes that task HOST will update the file and write "DONE".

This mechanism seems to work to what i need.

PS. I dont know what to call on this procedure, latch-release, idk, but i'm interested learning this kind of concept.
PPS. Hope there will be future update to docker to support multiple network interface.

Comment: I am returning to this answer, the way I am describing above is called "Messaging Pipeline". I was trying to understand JS Web Workers when I stumbled upon similar concept that I have done before. And so, adding this in my comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `-p`:

`-p WANIP:PORT:CONTAINERPORT/tcp -p INTERNALIP:PORT:CONTAINERPORT`